# How to remove, or change an attached template via OleAutomation

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole-automation

My company has a large selection of templates which are used to generate customer correspondence.  I need to modify the existing processes so that copies of generated files (template + data) are saved for later editing.

My problem is that when I open one of these saved MSWord documents, edit, then close, MSWord is insisting that changes have been made to the template (the one selected in the generation process).

I am not really sure why this is happening, but it may be that the generated document contains a reference to the template upon which it was based, but that because the template is in a remote location, MSWord is attempting to generate a new local file.

If that diagnosis is correct, then I need a method to remove the template reference from the document.

If the diagnosis is incorrect then what is the likely explanation/solution?

---

I have found that BOTH resultant files contain a reference to the template.

Note: Manual editing in Word has no issue. If I let the letter generate and save to disk from Winword, I can open it and manipulate it quite happily. Somewhere in the automation steps the problem is being created.

---

Interestingly - I have changed the save format to `'.rtf'` and the problem remains.

Further - it doesn't matter if I say 'Yes' to saving changes to the template, it continues to prompt me each time I open and close the document (whether I edit or not)

---

I have discovered that by saving the document as `wdFormatXML` I can see the reference to the letter template and edit it.  If I do that the problem goes away.

I am now attempting to achieve the same result via automation, but with no success;

```
  WordApp.ActiveDocument.Set_AttachedTemplate(tmplt);
```

Does not work for values of tmplt 'Normal.dot', varNull, 'c:\progra~1\etc\Simple.dotx' and so on.  The function call  tells me it cannot find the template for the first 2 of those values, or merely hangs.

I am back to my original question - how does one clear the attached template ?

Comment: In which format do are you saving your documents? If the file extension is *.doc or *.docx or *.docm then this is standard word document. But if your fie extension is *.dot or *.dotx or *.dotm then you are woking with the template format. So yeah changing these would result in warning about changing templates. So if you need to be creating new documents from these templates instead of opening them as file create a new document based on these templates. Saving that document should result in saving it into word document file and not document template.

Comment: `WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(strPath, wdFormatDocument);` results in a .doc file.

Comment: That is interestng. I have never seen such behavior before. Could you upload an example of such document somewhere on the web so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @SilverWarrior - I have established what the relevant property is of the document - it is 'AttachedTemplate'.  I have also shown that changing it to 'Normal.dot' resolves the issue.  I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it.  My problem was down to late-binding in some way.  I found that the following code worked

```
var
  docpath : OleVariant;
  fmt     : OleVariant;
  tmplt   : OleVariant;
  WordApp : WordApplication;
  WordDoc : WordDocument;
begin
  docpath := SaveLoggedDocToDisk(GetCurrentFileName());

  WordApp := CoWordApplication.Create;
  try
    fmt     := EDITABLE_FORMAT;
    tmplt   := '';

    WordDoc := WordApp.Documents.Open(docpath, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,  EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, fmt, EmptyParam, EmptyParam );
    WordDoc.Set_AttachedTemplate(tmplt);
```

The problem I had with earlier versions of this code was that

```
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SetAttachedTemplate(tmplt);
```

although it appears equivalent, was not behaving.  By creating a variable of type `WordDocument` the routine sprang into life.